# Setting a bone in a particular angle

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, armature, bones

I'm trying setting some bones in a particular way. One of my friends told me to set the bone on -180 0 0 PYR on Blender. However, to do that, I need to have the bones on a particular angle (0 0 0 I would say), but the armature comes with the bones already like this [image]

What I want to achieve is making the bones have this particular angle

[image]

The issue here is I can't really ask him how to do it since he uses 3DSMax.
So, my question is, since that's already the neutral position, is there a way to rotate that bone in that angle? (-180 0 0 PYR)

Thank you in advance, I hope you can help me with this!

Answer (score 1):

Key <kbd>R</kbd>, then the axis (<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd>), then the angle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added what I've tried to achieve